# Flutterflow in-app purchase via RevenueCat or custom widget

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store, flutterflow

I understand that RevenueCat manages app subscriptions, and Stripe also processes payments for additional items like shoes, movies, or services. Is it possible to use these for a remove-ads feature?

There are reports that Apple has rejected apps from the App Store because RevenueCat does not account for Apple's 30% fee (15% for the Play Store). I haven't been able to find clear information on this topic online or in this forum.

Thank you!